# Want to aggregate AWS cloudtrails from various accounts to a master AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudtrail

Got this working with the following solution, but was wondering if there was a better approach.

WORKING Solution

- CustomerA( Cloudtrails ) ---> CustomerA (Cloudwatch ) --> Master ( S3
  Bucket ) --> Master ( Lambda ) --> Master( Kinesis )

Tried the following, but could not get these to work ( Are these possible? )

- CustomerA( Cloudtrails ) --> CustomerA ( Cloudwatch ) --> Master (
  Lambda )
- CustomerA( Cloudtrails ) --> CustomerA ( Cloudwatch ) --> Master (
  Kinesis )

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? For example, why are you using Lambda and Kinesis? Do you just want to store the CloudTrail in an Amazon S3 bucket? Are you trying to combine files into one file, or keep each account separate?

Comment: Want to process various cloudtrails in a master account lambda

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to:

- Collect **AWS CloudTrail logs** from multiple AWS accounts into an Amazon S3 bucket in one ('master') AWS account
- Trigger an **AWS Lambda function** whenever a new CloudTrail log arrives

You can certainly [configure AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html) in multiple accounts to send log files to the same S3 bucket.

Amazon S3 can [trigger an event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) when the new object is created. This event can call an AWS Lambda function, passing in the name of the new S3 object.

[image: S3 triggering Lambda]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images/push-s3-example-10.png))</sub>

Lambda can process the file, performing **logic** based upon the API log data in the file.

Comment: I actually got S3 bucket solution working.  Just wondering if there is another way?

Comment: You don't need to go via CloudWatch Logs. The log file itself can trigger the Lambda function.